# how to include a folders containing images to product.wxs file in wix project

Tags: visual-studio, wix

I am new to WiX, I am facing a problem in adding a folder which contains necessary images and icons to wix project, I am able to include required dlls and files using

```
<Component Id='HelperLibrary'>
        <File Id='HelperDLL' Name='Helper.dll' />
</Component>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are working with a .NET project, adding of DLLs to the WIX installer from the project output folder of the referred project can be done as following by using the `TargetDir` item:

```
  <Component Guid="*" Directory="BinFolder">
    <File Id="BinFolder.Helper.dll" Source="$(var.ProjectToPackage.TargetDir)Helper.dll"/>
  </Component>
```

Similar way, you can add other files from the project whihch doesn't come under the project output can be added as following using the `ProjectDir` item from the referred project:

```
  <Component Guid="*" Directory="ImageFolder">
    <File Id="ImageFolder.Icon.jpg" Source="$(var.ProjectToPackage.ProjectDir)Icons\Icon.jpg" />
  </Component>
```

**Note:** Here it is expecting that your WIX project is having reference to the project to be packaged and the project reference is named as `ProjectToPackage` in this example above.

Comment: they way you suggested will include only one image file but I have many image files how to include them all? By no means it would be good to add them all one by one. @RinoTom

Comment: @Badrul, I am not sure whether WIX supports anything like that of having component item as a total folder. At least I never found being used anywhere. Probably we can wait for some better anwers in that case :)